# I define column index parameter in my arrow function but i can use in my useEffect causes is not define

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, react-resize-observer

I define column index parameter in my arrow function but I can use in my `useEffect` causes is not define! What can I do?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
      if (elementRef.current) {
        setBoxViewWidth(elementRef.current.clientWidth);
        if (elementRef.current.clientWidth < 1200) {
          elementRef.current.clientWidth.style.right = (boxViewWidth / 2) * (columnIndex % 2);
        } else if (elementRef.current.clientWidth < 992) {
          elementRef.current.clientWidth.style.right = (boxViewWidth / 1) * (columnIndex % 1);
        }
      }
    });
    if (elementRef.current) {
      resizeObserver.observe(elementRef.current);
    }
    return () => {
      resizeObserver.disconnect();
    };
  }, [boxViewWidth]);

 const RenderBox = ({ style, rowIndex, columnIndex }) => {
    console.log(style);
    return (
      rows && (
        <div
          style={{
            ...style,
            right: (boxViewWidth / 3) * (columnIndex % 3),
          }}
        >
        ......
```

Comment: `columnIndex` isn't declared in the `useEffect` hook callback so it is undefined.

Comment: so how can I declared?

Comment: Which element is referenced with `elementRef`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here:

- `columnIndex` referenced in the `useEffect` hook will be undefined, that is because the value of it will only be available in the context of `RenderBox`. So we need a different way to pass it. We can use an `data-*` attribute to achieve that easily.
- the value in the dependencies array passed to `useEffect` (I'm referring to `boxViewWidth`) might not be enough to account for all component updates. We'll also need `elementRef.current`
- `boxViewWidth` is updated twice with each run. This is not a huge issue here, but we can fix that too.
- there is no such thing as `HTMLElement.clientWidth.style.right`, I think we want `HTMLElement.style.right`, fixing that too.

The code then becomes:

```
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
  function updateBoxViewWidth() { 
      if (!elementRef.current) return
      if (elementRef.current.clientWidth === boxViewWidth) return
      
      setBoxViewWidth(elementRef.current.clientWidth)
  }
  
  updateBoxViewWidth()
}, [elementRef.current, boxViewWidth])

useEffect(() => {
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => {
      if (!elementRef.current) return
      const columnIndex = elementRef.current.getAttribute('data-column-index');
      
      if (elementRef.current.clientWidth < 1200) {
        elementRef.current.style.right = (boxViewWidth / 2) * (columnIndex % 2);
      } else if (elementRef.current.clientWidth < 992) {
        elementRef.current.style.right = (boxViewWidth / 1) * (columnIndex % 1);
      }
    });
    if (elementRef.current) 
      resizeObserver.observe(elementRef.current);
    
    return () => {
      if (elementRef.current)
        resizeObserver.disconnect();
    };
  }, [elementRef.current, boxViewWidth]);
  

 const RenderBox = ({ style, rowIndex, columnIndex }) => {
    console.log(style);
    return (
      rows && (
        <div
          data-column-index={columnIndex}
          style={{
            ...style,
            right: (boxViewWidth / 3) * (columnIndex % 3),
          }}
        >
```